# "object-fit: cover;" on Chrome renders images jagged

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, firefox, object-fit

I am using `object-fit: cover;` to display an image inside a square (or circle) while maintaining the original proportions of the image.

The only problem that I've noticed is that in Chrome if the image is taller than it is wide, it is shown as jagged. On Firefox, I don't notice this problem.

I have tried forcing the render using the GPU with `translateZ` or similar, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Here are some screenshots showing the problem (notice the difference between the last squares):

**Chrome (placeholder images)**

[image: Chrome object-fit example 1]

**Firefox (placeholder images)**

[image: Firefox object-fit example 1]

**Chrome (sample images)**

[image: Chrome object-fit example 2]

**Firefox (sample images)**

[image: Firefox object-fit example 1]

Tested on:

- Chrome v103.0.5060.114
- Firefox v102.0
- Fedora 35

Here's the example code:

```css
.box {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
}

.cover {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="box" src="https://dummyimage.com/640x640/000/fff" />
  <img class="box" src="https://dummyimage.com/640x320/000/fff" />
  <img class="box" src="https://dummyimage.com/800x1000/000/fff" />
</div>
<div>
  <img class="box cover" src="https://dummyimage.com/640x640/000/fff" />
  <img class="box cover" src="https://dummyimage.com/640x320/000/fff" />
  <img class="box cover" src="https://dummyimage.com/800x1000/000/fff" />
</div>
```

Why does this happen in Chrome?

Comment: Looks like this was logged recently https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1341991&q=object-fit&can=2